# Error working with google apps script locally in VSCode using CLASP and push command

Tags: google-apps-script, visual-studio-code, clasp

I have cloned a google apps script project but when trying to deploy the changes with the push command I get the following error:

> PS D:\evcPRD> clasp push

No valid D:\evcPRD.clasp.json project file. You may need to `create` or `clone` a project first.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: what is in the clasp.json file you are trying to push?

Comment: this is what it contains: {"scriptId":"1zE2zMqH7kedog3W-oJO-w-phpjffO9h8idrkwlMmuoCqiHFu5A6QZMpl","rootDir":"src"}

Comment: `cd` into `/src` before `push` or move `.clasp.json` to the parent `evcPRD`